# Electron application architecture - IPC vs API

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I am digging into Electron and I am now looking for the best way to create the architecture of an application.

So far it seems that the best thing to do would be to separate concerns - let the main process communicate with the system and the renderer handle the UI stuff.

There seems to be two different ways to let these two processes communicate that I've seen:

1. Through an API, having the main process spin up a hidden renderer process to use as a web worker running a server and then hit its endpoints from the " main renderer process"
2. Using IPC, having the main process listen to events from the renderer process

What I fail to see is a comparison of which approach is better and why.

- What are the pros/cons of using each of these two approaches?
- Is any of the two options strictly better than the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a local webserver will force the communication to use the HTTP/WS protocol and go through the computer's TCP/IP stack in order to finally reach the network card. This is expensive in many ways and there is no reason to follow this approach for a desktop application. So there's one thing (performance).

In terms of developer experience, if you only need to communicate between Electron's `main` and `renderer` processes, you'll be as fine as you'd be with any other callback based HTTP library. If you need to spawn other processes to do some event-loop-blocking stuff, then you'd need to implement a "promisified" IPC communication mechanism and configure webpack entries accordingly, which requires some work.

I have successfully followed the last approach, so if you need any help tell me in the comments.

Comment: In the end the way to go was definitely through IPC, it felt much more simple